# Shared list variable across all projects in a solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a a solution that have 3 projects (A, B and C).

Project A is a class Library that contains a list of objects that should be changed by project B or project C. And the other project have to be capable of see the new values under the list.

My doubt is how i can do this? I have tried (without sucess) to create a static class in project A. But if i do that, each project (B and C) will have a different reference to project A, so, if i, from project B, add a object to the list in project A, the project C don't see this object....

thanks in advance!

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Comment: Do you mean that project B and project C are separate applications, running as separate processes? If so, it sounds like you may well want a persistent data store (e.g. a database) instead.

Comment: Do you reload the list in C, after you added the object in B?

Comment: It's sounds like your A class should be a static Singleton class. Look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx